# MySQL error: "1030 - Got error -1 from storage engine"

Tags: mysql

I received the following message while working while working with a pre-existing existing database and adding some new tables
Error Msg

```
#1030 - Got error -1 from storage engine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually means you've ran out of disk space.  Check using `df -h` and delete any large log files or other files taking up a lot of space.

Failing that, check your memory usage.

Comment: how can i delete the log file in my server ?

Comment: If you find a large log file that isn't needed, just remove it using the `rm` command.  I don't just mean MySQL logs, look for any large files that aren't required on your server.

Comment: i delete log in folder logs in my server and also get this message

Comment: i noticed that the cashed memory from phpmyadmin is high how can i fix it

Answer (score 2):

This error is mainly due to the low memory which means that you don't have enough memory for allocating to your table or database.

Please have a look [here](http://wiki.jumpbox.com/doc/runtime/faq/mysql_maintenance).It would be helpful.

Comment: also get the same message

Comment: i noticed that the cashed memory from phpmyadmin is high how can i fix it

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error if **/etc/my.cnf** you have **innodb_force_recovery** turned on.  Comment out that option, restart the server and try the data import again.