# MySQL 5.7 Error 1030

Tags: mysql

I would like to create table with MyISAM engine on MySQL 5.7
But I getting this error:

Error number 1030: Got Error 1 from storage engine

this is my query:

```
Create table `job_type(  
  `type_id` tinyint(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  primary key (`type_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

How to fix this issue ?

Solution:

Azure MySQL does not support MyISAM

[Creating MyISAM Table in Azure database for MySQL is enable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973881/creating-myisam-table-in-azure-database-for-mysql-is-enable)

Thank You

Comment: You appear to have missed the closing backtick in your table name.

Comment: Assuming that missing backtick is just a typo, a quick search for error code `1030` reveals a lack of memory as being one cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591708/mysql-error-1030-got-error-1-from-storage-engine

Comment: Sorry, I found it. Azure MySQL does not support MyISAM. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973881/creating-myisam-table-in-azure-database-for-mysql-is-enable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating MyISAM Table in Azure database for MySQL is enable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973881/creating-myisam-table-in-azure-database-for-mysql-is-enable)

Comment: Is MyISAM enabled? `show engines`. Do you have enough disk space?

Answer (score 2):

MyISAM is not supported in Azure. You have to use InnoDB.